# Удаление реакции дискорд в on_raw_reaction_add

Tags: python, discord

Как можно удалить реакцию пользователя сразу после того как он ее проставил используя события on_raw_reaction_add.

Весь код:

```
import asyncio
import sqlite3
import config
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = Bot( command_prefix = '.')
base = sqlite3.connect('ЧС.db')
cur = base.cursor()
Client = discord.Client()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True,manage_messages=True)
async def чс(ctx, arg=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if arg == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x000000, description =f'Доступные команды:\n .чс добавить *NICK* *ID*\n .чс убрать *NICK*\n .чс список')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif arg == 'добавить':
        try:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?)', (arg2, arg3))
            base.commit()
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Данный ник успешно добавлен в черный список')

        except:
            await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Данный ник или ID уже есть в черном списке')

    elif arg == 'убрать':
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM data WHERE name == ?', (arg2,))
        base.commit()
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Данный ник был удален из черного списока')

    elif arg == 'список':
        c = base.cursor()
        s = c.execute('SELECT * FROM data').fetchall()
        global embedBLACK
        embedBLACK = discord.Embed(color = 0x000000, description ='Черный список: \n')
        number = 0
        for r in s:
            number += 1
            embedBLACK.add_field(name='№', value=f'{number}')
            embedBLACK.add_field(name='Имя:', value=r[0])
            embedBLACK.add_field(name='ID', value=r[1])

        global blackLIST, left, right
        blackLIST = await ctx.send(embed=embedBLACK)
        left = await blackLIST.add_reaction('⬅️')
        right = await blackLIST.add_reaction('➡️')


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = payload.channel_id
    mess = blackLIST.id
    i = 0
    print('start')

    if not payload.member.bot:
        if payload.message_id == mess:
            print('Тот id')

            if payload.emoji.name == '⬅️':
                print('Нажатие левой стрелки')
                if i <= 0:
                    i = 0
                i -=9
                row = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data LIMIT {}, 9'.format(i)).fetchall()
                edition = discord.Embed(color = 0x000000, description ='Черный список: \n')
                edition.clear_fields()
                embedBLACK.clear_fields()

                number = 0
                for r in row:
                    number += 1
                    edition.add_field(name='№', value=f'{number}')
                    edition.add_field(name='Имя:', value=r[0])
                    edition.add_field(name='ID', value=r[1])

                await blackLIST.edit(embed=edition)
                await bot.remove_reaction(member)

            if payload.emoji.name == '➡️':
                print('Нажатие правой стрелки')
                if i <= 0:
                    i = 0

                i +=9
                row = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data LIMIT {}, 9'.format(i)).fetchall()
                edition = discord.Embed(color = 0x000000, description ='Черный список: \n')
                edition.clear_fields()
                embedBLACK.clear_fields()

                number = 0
                for r in row:
                    number += 1
                    edition.add_field(name='№', value=f'{number}')
                    edition.add_field(name='Имя:', value=r[0])
                    edition.add_field(name='ID', value=r[1])

                await blackLIST.edit(embed=edition)

                await bot.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)


bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: дополнил ответ получением объекта сообщения, посмотрите, если непонятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await message.remove_reaction(эмоджи, автор_реакции)
```

**То есть вот так:**

```
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
await message.remove_reaction(str(payload.emoji), payload.member)
```

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понял как вызывать данные атрибуты с помощью вашего примера.